# Common Lisp: Replace IF with AND & OR?

Tags: common-lisp

I am stuck with exercise 4.28. of the book A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation (p. 129):

> We can usually rewrite an IF as a combination of AND plus OR by
>   following this simple scheme: Replace (IF *test true-part false-part*)
>   with the equivalent expression (OR (AND *test true-part*)
>   *false-part*). But this scheme fails for the expression (IF (ODDP 5) (EVENP 7) ’FOO). Why does it fail? Suggest a more sophisticated way to
>   rewrite IF as a combination of ANDs and ORs that does not fail.

`(or (and (oddp 5) (or (evenp 7) t)) 'foo)` evaluates the *true-part* and stops, and it would evaluate the *false-part* if *test* were NIL, but it always returns T if *test* is T, which does not reflect the behaviour of IF. Is there a correct solution to the problem with what one has learned so far in the book, or is the answer to the exercise that there is none at this point?

I am not asking for the solution for the exercise if there is one, just whether it makes sense for me to continue looking for one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close. It fails because `(EVENP 7)` (the consequent) happens to be the false value `NIL` and then the whole `and` form turns into `NIL` and `or` will evaluate the alternative.

Yes. There is a way to fix this even when only knowing the forms you already have presented in the question, but it might not work with side effects (expressions that print stuff) in the future.

Comment: @Pascal In addition to the multiple evaluation caveat the formulation I see also needs `not`.